# Is there a way of achieving something similar to get_template_part() in the functions folder?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am wondering if there is a way of doing something similar to `<?php get_template_part(); ?>` in the `functions.php` file – I am specifically hoping to target Woocommerce with this code.

Most of my website's pages use the following code from my default template – `page.php`

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php get_template_part('includes/side-menu'); ?>

<div class="content">

    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have set up my theme (custom built) for use with the Woocommerce plugin, but I'm having an issue with a side-menu in my theme that is in a separate folder from my header and footer. Woocommerce uses its own templates to generate its pages, i.e. the product archive and product pages etc. Each of these templates call my theme's header and footer by default, but they don't call my menu, so when I press the button to open it on one of those pages, it isn't there.

I have set up Woocommerce to be compatible with my theme using the method recommended by the plugin authors. I have added the following code to my `functions.php`

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);


add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_start', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_end', 10);

function my_theme_wrapper_start() {
  echo '<div id="woocommerce-content" class="content"> <div class="container">';
}

function my_theme_wrapper_end() {
  echo '</div> </div>';
}
```

This code allows me to add a div to the Woocommerce templates to wrap my content. I am wondering if there is a way of changing this code so I can call in my menu template `side-menu.php` on Woocommerce template pages.

There is another way of doing this, but I am trying to avoid using it because it involves a lot more work in the long term. It is possible to override the plugin template files by copying them into a folder within my theme, and adding the `<?php get_template_part(); ?>` code to call my side-menu.

The only problem with this is that it means that with every significant update to the plugin, I have to update these override files to include new code released with Woocommerce updates, because it doesn't update them automatically.

If there is any way of calling the side-menu as a blanket action throughout Woocommerce pages in the same way that the code above adds the HTML, that would be a much easier solution.

I'm interested to hear if this is possible.

Comment: Not sure if it would be in the right place, but couldn't you just call `get_template_part('includes/side-menu');` in the `my_theme_wrapper_start()` function?

Comment: Hi, I thought about that, but it would come up inside my content div, which could cause problems. I might give it a try though